# Remove Commas from my textfield

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, split, textfield

I have a problem when inserting elements from my XML to a textfield.

When I trace my code I get all my elements without any commas, but when I insert it into a textfield i'm getting alot of commas.

I've tried to split up the text to remove the commas, but there aren't any commas in the XML so how do I do this?

Here's my code

```
var B:Array = [];
var textLength:int = imgData.Vehicle.EquipmentList.children().length();
var list:XMLList = imgData.Vehicle.EquipmentList.children();
var equipmentList:XMLList = list.text();
for(var t = 0; t < textLength; t++)
{

    var equipText:String = list[t];
    equipText.split(",");
    B.push(equipText);
    trace(equipText);
    //B = B.split(", ").join();
}

errorMessage.text = B.toString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commas are added by toString() method.
See http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#toString().

You should use join() method instead.

```
errorMessage.text = B.join("");
```